# Android App Crashes When Trying to Run Settings Activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm trying to create a settings activity, where the user is on the profile screen and is able to click the settings button to access the settings activity. However, the app crashes when trying to run the settings activity.

I have looked at the RunTime error and I believe pref_main.xml is the file that is giving the issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Debata xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/pref_title_account">
    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="@string/default_full_name"
        android:key="@string/key_full_name"
        android:summary="@string/default_full_name"
        android:title="@string/title_name" />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="@string/default_username"
        android:key="@string/key_username"
        android:summary="@string/default_username"
        android:title="@string/title_username" />

    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="@string/default_birthday"
        android:key="@string/key_birthday"
        android:summary="@string/default_birthday"
        android:title="@string/title_birthday" />

    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="@string/default_email"
        android:key="@string/key_email"
        android:summary="@string/default_email"
        android:title="@string/title_email" />
</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/pref_title_notifications">
    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="@string/enable_notifications"
        android:title="@string/title_enable_notifications" />

    <RingtonePreference
        android:defaultValue="content://settings/system/notification_sound"
        android:dependency="enable_notifications"
        android:key="@string/key_ringtone"
        android:ringtoneType="notification"
        android:summary="@string/default_ringtone"
        android:title="@string/title_ringtone" />

    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="@string/key_vibrate"
        android:title="@string/title_vibrate" />
</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/pref_title_more_info">
    <Preference
        android:summary="@string/app_version"
        android:title="@string/title_version" />

    <Preference android:title="@string/title_privacy_policy">
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:data="@string/pdf_privacy_policy" />
    </Preference>

    <Preference android:title="@string/title_terms_conditions">
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:data="@string/pdf_terms_conditions" />
    </Preference>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

```
public static class MainPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_main);

        // EditText Listeners
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.key_full_name)));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.key_username)));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.key_birthday)));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.key_email)));

        // notification preference change listener
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.key_ringtone)));
    }
}
```

This was the result that I got when I looked at the RunTime error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: app.debata.com.debata, PID: 8085
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.debata.com.debata/app.debata.com.debata.SettingsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class Debata

And in the Runtime error message I had a line that said this:
 app.debata.com.debata.SettingsActivity$MainPreferenceFragment.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:37)
```

If you refer to the above code and look at the onCreate method inside the MainPreferenceFragement class, that RunTime error is right inside that code. That method is part of the SettingsActivity.java file.

Can anyone tell me why my android app is crashing when trying to run the settings activity?

Edit: Full Log File

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: app.debata.com.debata, PID: 8085
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.debata.com.debata/app.debata.com.debata.SettingsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class Debata
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2955)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class Debata
        at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:443)
        at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:318)
        at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:264)
        at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:324)
        at android.preference.PreferenceFragment.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceFragment.java:326)
        at app.debata.com.debata.SettingsActivity$MainPreferenceFragment.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:37)
        at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2593)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1234)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2421)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2200)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2154)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2055)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchMoveToState(FragmentManager.java:3050)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2997)
        at android.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:179)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreateCommon(Activity.java:7177)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7185)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2908)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374) 
E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.preference.Debata" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/app.debata.com.debata-VQM2DR9s3CjomJtnF5Qdyw==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/app.debata.com.debata-VQM2DR9s3CjomJtnF5Qdyw==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/app.debata.com.debata-VQM2DR9s3CjomJtnF5Qdyw==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/app.debata.com.debata-VQM2DR9s3CjomJtnF5Qdyw==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/app.debata.com.debata-VQM2DR9s3CjomJtnF5Qdyw==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/app.debata.com.debata-VQM2DR9s3CjomJtnF5Qdyw==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/app.debata.com.debata-VQM2DR9s3CjomJtnF5Qdyw==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/app.debata.com.debata-VQM2DR9s3CjomJtnF5Qdyw==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/app.debata.com.debata-VQM2DR9s3CjomJtnF5Qdyw==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/app.debata.com.debata-VQM2DR9s3CjomJtnF5Qdyw==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/app.debata.com.debata-VQM2DR9s3CjomJtnF5Qdyw==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/app.debata.com.debata-VQM2DR9s3CjomJtnF5Qdyw==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/app.debata.com.debata-VQM2DR9s3CjomJtnF5Qdyw==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/app.debata.com.debata-VQM2DR9s3CjomJtnF5Qdyw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:376)
        at android.preference.GenericInflater.onCreateItem(GenericInflater.java:419)
        at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:430)
            ... 27 more
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location (arm64) /data/app/app.debata.com.debata-VQM2DR9s3CjomJtnF5Qdyw==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:100)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:74)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:157)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(PathClassLoaderFactory.java:43)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:69)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:36)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:678)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:711)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:944)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2303)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5937)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764)
                ... 6 more
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location (arm64) /data/app/app.debata.com.debata-VQM2DR9s3CjomJtnF5Qdyw==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:100)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:74)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:157)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(PathClassLoaderFactory.java:43)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:69)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:36)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:678)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:711)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:944)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2303)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5937)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764)
                ... 6 more
```

Comment: as you can see from the logs you provided the problem compiler is unable to understand `Debata `class.

Comment: @Umair Why is it not able to understand Debata class? The app was working fine before until I tried to run the Settings class.

Comment: Well you have to see why it is not inflating Debata class. and without your complete log file I can't see exactly what is the problem.

Comment: @Umair I just edited the posted and included the complete log file.

Comment: I haven't seen this class before though, because if you generate settings activity through android studio it starts with `<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">` or something similar or `Debata`

Comment: try replacing Debata with PreferenceScreen ...

Comment: @Umair That fixed it. Do you know why when I edit the text it doesn't show the new text? For example, in the first `EditTextPreference`, when I edit the name, it still shows what was originally in `android:summary` which was the default text `name`. How do I change it to display the new text, something like Michael?

Comment: That's maybe you are not setting the text properly. I suggest you should go through the tutorials related to settings activity first :)